# How to stuff Brown Sugar croissants?

Tags: dessert, brown-sugar

When looking at a recipe about Brown Sugar croissants I found a slight problem. These are supposed to be desserts. However I can't find a way to place the sugar in the roll without the croissant falling apart. Any ideas?

As a crude translation (because the book is in French) it says to stuff brown sugar inside the lip of the croissant (meaning the small flap that folds) and put butter or lard on to harden the roll back up.

Comment: Could you show us the recipe? I'm guessing this is something with premade crescent roll dough?

Comment: @Jefromi It's in a 1950's "Cooking dans la Paris" cookbook.

Comment: Okay, so again, could you show us the recipe, at least whatever it says about how to fill them? (Even if it's in French - someone will be able to translate.) Is it supposed to be all the way through, or just a pocket in the middle? This isn't, as far as I know, a common thing a lot of people are going to know how to make, especially given that it's from 60 years ago.

Comment: I was also trying to find the cookbook (sometimes things have been scanned in Google Books) but that title doesn't look correct.

Comment: There are native French speakers around here, if you would like to post the actual French and do better than a crude translation. I'm not sure what you mean by "lip" or "small flap that folds" - putting it in the tiny corner that's the last to roll up doesn't make much sense to me. If you're just putting the sugar in the wide part of the triangle, which becomes the center of the croissant, then I don't see how it'd make it fall apart.

Comment: From the limited information so far available, it looks like you spread the filling in a small stripe at the base of the triangle that will become the croissant, much as you would place a stick of chocolate for a chocolate croissant.  I suspect the cinnamon and sugar are more an accent than they are in, for example, cinnamon buns.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided any additional information, I'm just going to provide our best guess here, what SAJ14SAJ and I were both thinking.

If you want to put something in a croissant, whether it's a piece of chocolate or any other filling, the normal way is to put a strip of it along the side of the triangle which becomes the inside of the croissant. That way it gets completely surrounded when you roll it up and has no effect on the croissant holding together. This should work just fine for brown sugar. Just make sure not to go all the way out to the ends, or it may melt and seep out as you bake.

From the little you said, the hardening up with butter or lard sounds like it's just a way to crisp up the outside. (Brushing with butter is a technique not limited to croissants.)

And finally, a wild guess, based on your crude translation: "lip" as in "projecting opening"  (like perhaps the lip of a container) [can be translated](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/lip) to "bord" or "rebord" in French; if your recipe said one of those, a better translation would be "edge" or "side", which is entirely consistent with what I said above.